# first element of div inside div

Tags: html, css

Code

```
<div class="row mgu-w-tdw-brow">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-widget-teaser-1x1">...</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-teaser-list-1x1-large">...</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-teaser-list-1x1-large">...</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-widget-teaser-1x1">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mgu-w-tdw-brow div.mgu-w-tdw-box:first-child { border: 2px solid green; }
```

I'd like to approach the first element of "mgu-w-tdw-box" inside the row "mgu-w-tdw-brow". Unfortunately this doesn't work.

thanks for help.

Comment: did you added bootstrap css ?

Comment: yeah, part of the framework..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what you need, first select `div:first-child` and style inside div

```css
.mgu-w-tdw-brow div:first-child .mgu-w-tdw-box {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row mgu-w-tdw-brow">
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-widget-teaser-1x1">...</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-teaser-list-1x1-large">...</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-teaser-list-1x1-large">...</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-widget-teaser-1x1">...</div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: please tick the answer if its working for you thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a better readable version which does the same for this example.

```
.mgu-w-tdw-brow >:first-child {
 border: 2px solid green;
 }
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6v6p7mh/) for it.

Comment: I know its not that tidy and all first Elements in the div will be green. Just a simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mgu-w-tdw-brow  [class*="col"]:nth-child(1) .mgu-w-tdw-box{
border:solid 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row mgu-w-tdw-brow">
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-widget-teaser-1x1">...</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-teaser-list-1x1-large">...</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-teaser-list-1x1-large">...</div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="mgu-w-tdw-box mgu-widget-teaser-1x1">...</div>
</div>
  
</div>
```